# How can I get the used/free managed disk size on Azure VMs?

Tags: azure, azure-managed-disk

I have some Azure VMs, and appended some managed disks to the. But is it possible that get the free/used size of these managed disks?

I have tried [Get-AzDisk powershell](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azdisk?view=azps-5.3.0) command.However it only returns the total size if Disks instead of the used/free size of a disk. How can I get used/free size of a disk by PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Run command functionality to do this.
For windows VMs please refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#powershell) and [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command#powershell) is for Linux VMs.

For instance, if you are using Azure Windows VM, you can use PowerShell Command below to get the information you need:

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -Name <vm name> -ResourceGroupName <Resource Group Name>

$result = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -VM $vm -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath '<path of your PS script that run inside of VM>'

$result.Value[0].Code
$result.Value[0].Message
```

Content of PS script that runs inside of VM:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceID,size,FreeSpace
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you will not able to do it without log analytics..
Use LogAnalyticsWorkspace and connect them to your VMs, using inbuilt or custom queries you can extract space details.